# How to position image in the extjs panel as required.?

Tags: html, css, extjs, extjs4

I have panel which links other components to render on-demand. I have a background image to this panel. I need to display Company logo at the bottom-right/top-left/top-right/bottom-left of the panel at run time. Due to other components rendering in the same panel I cannot change the layout to some other. I want to apply CSS, so that my logo will be positioned as required.

Your help is much appreciated!

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a css class to the panels body you can do it like this:

```
Panel.body.addCls("logo");
```

And the css needs to look something like this:

```
.logo
 {
    background-image: url(logo.png);
    background-position: top right, top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

This will display the logos in the top right and top left of panels body.

Comment: Thanks I got it too :). But the panel layout is vbox-center-center, so the CSS wont apply here. I got to look for something else.